# How to enable neon coproocessor in am335x(cortex A8)?

Tags: compilation, kernel, neon, cortex-a8

I am using TI Sitara am335x processor. I have to use neon co rpocessor for cryptographic purposes. This link tells how to enable it. I added it in kernel/init/main.c. Upon compilation I got the error message "**selected processor does not support ARM mode `fmxr FPEXC,r2**'". What does it mean? Any flag required while compiling the kernel?

Answer (score 1):

`-mfpu=neon` is the compiler flag that you are looking for.

Comment: yes, include it with all the other flags present in the makefile

Comment: I added it only in CFLAGS_KERNEL of makefile. Din't work. By the way I am using TI sdk 5.0 (also called arago). Does using armcc compiler solve it?